# Django ORM: Join to queryset models with foreign key

Tags: django, django-orm

I need to get list of all companies and join the company user with minimal `companyuser` id.
There are two models:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    kind = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CompanyUser(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    #other fields
```

I've tried something like this:

```
companies = Company.objects.all().select_related(Min('companyuser__email'))
```

but It doesn't work. How can I do this with Django ORM? Is there any way to do it without raw SQL?

Comment: What do you mean `minimal id`?

Comment: I mean minimal id in database. `companyuser.id`

Comment: The id is automatically assigned by the system and you should not rely on this for ordering or other purposes. Are you trying to order companies by the _number of users_?

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Min
Company.objects.annotate(lowest_companyuser_id=Min("companyuser__id"))
```

## Explanation

`select_related()` can be used for telling Django which related tables should be joined to the resulting queryset for reducing the number of queries, namely solving the dreaded "N+1 problem" when looping over a queryset and accessing related objects in iteration. ([see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related))

With using `Min()` you were on the right track, but it ought to be used in conjunction with the `annotate()` queryset method. Using `annotate()` with aggregate expressions like `Min()`, `Max()`, `Count()`, etc. translates in an SQL query using one of the aforementioned aggregate expressions with `GROUP BY`. (see [docs about annotate() in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#annotate), about [GROUP BY in Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY))

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

As Burhan said - do not rely on the pk, but if u must...

```
companies = Company.objects.all().order_by('pk')[0]
```